# Simple linear regression between timeseries raster datasets

Tags: r, raster, lm

I want to run simple linear regression between two (NPP and Tmax) different grid raster datasets. The datasets are annual dataset with similar resolution and time.
The first raster dataset is

```
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 321, 401, 128721, 37  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.0375, 0.0375  (x, y)
extent     : 32.98125, 48.01875, 2.98125, 15.01875  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : Tmax_ANNUAL_RES01.tif 
names      : Tmax_ANNUAL_RES01.1, Tmax_ANNUAL_RES01.2, Tmax_ANNUAL_RES01.3, 
Tmax_ANNUAL_RES01.4, Tmax_ANNUAL_RES01.5, Tmax_ANNUAL_RES01.6, Tmax_ANNUAL_RES01.7, 
Tmax_ANNUAL_RES01.8, Tmax_ANNUAL_RES01.9, Tmax_ANNUAL_RES01.10, Tmax_ANNUAL_RES01.11, 
Tmax_ANNUAL_RES01.12, Tmax_ANNUAL_RES01.13, Tmax_ANNUAL_RES01.14, Tmax_ANNUAL_RES01.15, 
... 
min values :            12.63056,            13.49100,            12.90514,            
11.87769,            12.35822,            12.49712,            12.41137,            
11.83172,            12.46157,             13.08855,             12.18255,             
12.03794,             12.18468,             12.58404,             12.60854, ... 
max values :            40.78825,            39.08575,            41.42342,            
38.99245,            38.76424,            39.27279,            38.86973,            
38.87597,            41.17113,             42.31324,             40.92870,             
42.30246,             42.61915,             43.22092,             41.89821, ...
```

and  The second raster dataset is

```
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 321, 401, 128721, 37  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.0375, 0.0375  (x, y)
extent     : 32.98125, 48.01875, 2.98125, 15.01875  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : NPP_ANNUAL_RES01.tif 
names      : NPP_ANNUAL_RES01.1, NPP_ANNUAL_RES01.2, NPP_ANNUAL_RES01.3, 
NPP_ANNUAL_RES01.4, NPP_ANNUAL_RES01.5, NPP_ANNUAL_RES01.6, NPP_ANNUAL_RES01.7, 
NPP_ANNUAL_RES01.8, NPP_ANNUAL_RES01.9, NPP_ANNUAL_RES01.10, NPP_ANNUAL_RES01.11, 
NPP_ANNUAL_RES01.12, NPP_ANNUAL_RES01.13, NPP_ANNUAL_RES01.14, NPP_ANNUAL_RES01.15, ... 
min values :                  0,                  0,                  0,                  
0,                  0,                  0,                  0,                  0,                  
0,                   0,                   0,                   0,                   0,                   
0,                   0, ... 
max values :             298.26,             276.47,             281.04,             
274.46,             293.88,             287.74,             289.74,             266.93,             
299.57,              310.09,              304.33,              304.29,              
292.32,              295.15,              283.13, ...
```

After stacking them the raster datasets is presented as

```
 stack_ANNUAL <- stack(list.files(pattern="*.tif", full.names=TRUE))

class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 321, 401, 128721, 74  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.0375, 0.0375  (x, y)
extent     : 32.98125, 48.01875, 2.98125, 15.01875  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
names      : NPP_ANNUAL_RES01.1, NPP_ANNUAL_RES01.2, NPP_ANNUAL_RES01.3, 
NPP_ANNUAL_RES01.4, NPP_ANNUAL_RES01.5, NPP_ANNUAL_RES01.6, NPP_ANNUAL_RES01.7, 
NPP_ANNUAL_RES01.8, NPP_ANNUAL_RES01.9, NPP_ANNUAL_RES01.10, NPP_ANNUAL_RES01.11, 
NPP_ANNUAL_RES01.12, NPP_ANNUAL_RES01.13, NPP_ANNUAL_RES01.14, NPP_ANNUAL_RES01.15, ... 
min values :            0.00000,            0.00000,            0.00000,            
0.00000,            0.00000,            0.00000,            0.00000,            0.00000,            
0.00000,             0.00000,             0.00000,             0.00000,             
0.00000,             0.00000,             0.00000, ... 
max values :          298.26001,          276.47000,          281.04001,          
274.45999,          293.88000,          287.73999,          289.73999,          
266.92999,          299.57001,           310.09000,           304.32999,           
304.29001,           292.32001,           295.14999,           283.13000, ...
```

The i run the following script to predict NPP from Tmax and want to know the slope

```
fun=function(x) { if (is.na(x[1])){ NA } else { lm(x[1:37] ~ x[38:74])$coefficients[2] }}
slope <- calc(stack_ANNUAL, fun)
```

But, the script  come up with

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, table)  : 
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘writeValues’ for signature 
‘"RasterBrick", "numeric"’
```

What is the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Question: Can you run the linear model as `lm(x[1:37] ~ x[38:74]`? how are you expected this to work out?

Comment: I got the script  from (https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2012-May/014979.html) and customized to my own grid raster dataset.

Comment: I can think of a few ways in which you could do this but your approach won't work because of your linear model set-up

Comment: Any suggestion please?

Comment: How do you expect the linear model to work? . Are you expecting `lm(x[1] ~ x[2]), lm(x[2]~x[3]) ...` in this fashion? Please make it clear what you want to do with the linear models because it's very unclear. Then I can help you further

Comment: I want to predict the NPP from Tmax (Both are grid dataset)

Comment: Have you thought of using the newer library `terra` rather than `raster`? from my opinion, it is easier to work with in general.

Comment: No, just googling such kind of webpage for some assignments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with how you have set up your function for the linear model.

An alternative may be the following:

```
#since your rasters have the same number of layers we pick any for 'n'
n <- names(NPP) %>% seq_along() %>% max()
#store your independent rasters into separate lists
NPP_list <- c()
TMAX_list <- c()
for( i in 1:n){
  NPP_list[i]<- list(NPP[[i]])
  TMAX_list[i]<- list(TMAX[[i]])
}

#store the rasters into dataframes and remove any na values
NPP_dataframe <- lapply(NPP_list, function(x)data.frame(na.omit(values(x))))
TMAX_dataframe <- lapply(TMAX_list, function(x)data.frame(na.omit(values(x))))

#Map a linear model between the the datasets
mapply(function(x,y)lm(x[[1]] ~ y[[1]], NPP_dataframe, TMAX_dataframe, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```